# DNN module error after trying to move it from dnn7 to dnn9

Tags: dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke, dnn9

I previously have this FAQ module installed on an old system running on DNN 7 and I tried using the same module on a site running on DNN 9.4.1 and I get the following errors:

[image: Error 1]

and

[image: Error 2]

I obtained the resourse file of this module from the package creator on the old system (DNN7) and installed it onto the new system (DNN9).

Does this happen because of the way i got the resource package or does it have to do with compatibility issues like this module is not supported by later versions of DNN?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DNN 9.2 & later the Telerik Grid Components were moved to a Deprecated assembly from the standard DotnetNuke.WebControls so all references to these wrappers, such as dnngrid will need to be updated.